# Python, how to convert an existing parent class object to child class object

Tags: python, types, casting

*** To give a reason why I wanna do the following, I am trying to wrap the third-party tool and do more with it.

I am using a third-party tool, it returns an object as a result. (e.g. An object of class `Person`, which contains **MANY** attributes).

I want to declare a new class, e.g. `Driver(Person)`. Which contain everything that is in `Person` class, and more. I am **NOT ALLOWED** to modify the `Person` class.

I already have an existing `Person` object(returned from the third-party tool), how do I cast it into a `Driver` object? Not by initializing a new empty `Driver` object and copying everything one by one into it please... In my case, there's over 30 attributes and properties in the Person class, and Person class is not the only class I need to do this with. I have to do this with about 20 classes. This is why it is not practical for me to copy from scratch one by one for each class unless there's no other way.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name


class Driver(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._gender = None

    @property
    def gender(self):
        return self._gender

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.gender}'
```

Given an instance of `Person`, cast it into a `Driver`. but imagine there's way more attributes in both classes. 
Currently, I basically just loaded the Person instance into a new Driver instance as an attribute. But I think there's gotta be a smarter way to do this.

Comment: How will you know the values for all the information that is part of a Driver but not already provided by the Person?

Comment: I will add those after everything from Person copied into Driver. What I've given is a very basic example, the actual data structure is a lot more complex. I need to do a lot of information extension in the new class, and analysis.

Comment: You could implement a class method....

Comment: @3vts Can you elaborate a little more on what implement a class exactly mean?

Comment: Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/classmethod-in-python/)

Comment: @3vts Thank you! I am not exactly clear on how this would help. I forgot to mention, I am not allowed to modify Person class. I can only create my own Driver class.

Comment: Not necessary. You can create a class function that creates a driver from a person instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210552/discussion-between-huadong-feng-and-3vts).

Comment: Consider whether you actually need inheritance, rather than making the given `Person` object an attribute of your `Driver` instance.

Comment: @chepner That's exactly what I did now. But I feel there's gotta be a smart way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically all attributes from a class live inside the magic `__dict__` attribute. This dictionary-like object contains all the attributes defined for the object itself.

So a way to copy *all* attributes at once will be to copy the `__dict__` attribute from a class to another either inside a method or from an instance like this:

```
a = Person()
b = Driver()
b.__dict__.update(a.__dict__)
```

Please note that if there are repeated attributes those will be overwritten so be careful